# abs at home workouts-diet

Tags: exercise, strength-training, abdominals, exercise-technique

I have watched a lot of videos on YouTube and have searched on Google but I am disappointed because my abs aren't as defined as I think they should be. My food intake is good, I have cut out sugar and am not eating anything that contains sugar.

My questions are:

1. Should I eat a lot of fruits and vegetables too for abs?
2. What workouts will be the most effective for my abs?

I don't have the money to go to a gym so I can only train at home.

What workouts will give me obvious results, because I have worked a lot on my abs. I know food is playing an important role but I think my abs routine isn't good. I train abs everyday only in the morning.

I hope to give me good information, I am not a professional and may do somethings wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is a genetic factor that plays a role on how your abs will look. However, the best (only) way to get defined abs is to lower your body fat percentage - which would be obtained by staying in a caloric deficit, so eating healthy is optimal.

Ab workouts help to further shape your abs and improve definition. I would recommend doing workouts which target different parts of the abs so add more variety to your core workouts (leg raises, planks, air bikes, reverse crunches, etc) rather than just basic sit-ups and crunches. Try to stay in the 8-15 rep range for your workouts. Increasing the protein in your diet with these workouts will also help you notice more muscle gain.

Also, if you are able to train core everyday you are not going hard enough. You should train your core 3-4 times a week, but when you do train it, give it your best. You should let your abs rest so they can grow and get stronger.